# Grails - NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, jqgrid, easygui

**Error**:

```
 [main] WARN org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication - 
 NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided
 (Mechanism level: No valid credentials 
 provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
```

I'm using:

```
Grails 2.3.8
GGTS 3.5.1    
Groory 2.1.9
Java 1.7
```

When I am going to change in BuildConfig.groovy like

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {

        plugins {    
          // EasyGrid plugin http://grails.org/plugin/easygrid      
            compile ":easygrid:1.6.2"       
            // For minimum functionality you need: jquery-ui and the export plugins.        
            // Export Plugin http://grails.org/plugin/export        
            compile ":export:1.5"       
            // jQuery UI Plugin http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui      
            compile":jquery-ui:1.10.3"      
            // For google visualization you also need google-visualization      
            // Google Visualization API Plugin
           //  http://grails.org/plugin/google-visualization    
            compile":google-visualization:0.7"
       }
}
```

While executing it gives error like -

```
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.6.2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)**
```

Then facing this type of issue.. Not able to resolve it please help me.
If you want more detail  regarding this I can provide.

Comment: I suppose is a proxy problem. http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html

Comment: I have successfully executed this command and it worked for me before but when I changed in **BulidConfig.groovy** then only I have this error message. Command is   "grails     add-proxy client -- host  = ***** -- port = **** --                username = ****\\****  -- password = *****             
  grails set-proxy client"

Comment: compile":jquery-ui:1.10.3"   <-- white space?

Comment: yes white space is there.

Comment: Thanks @chf I got it. It is because of proxy set up only, But when proxy is configured successfully then I have another error message like I show you in different answer. pls visit to below answer....

Comment: Link to new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807356/failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-for-org-grails-pluginseasygridzip1-6-2