# Grails : Failed to read artifact descriptor

Tags: maven, grails, jqgrid

While using EasyGrid plugins into BuildConfig.groovy I am not able to clean and run after adding plugins into BuildConfig.groovy. Facing such error message what to do to get rid of this pls.

**changes in BuildConfig.groovy   plugins {**

```
// EasyGrid plugin http://grails.org/plugin/easygrid
        compile ":easygrid:1.6.2"
        // For minimum functionality you need: jquery-ui and the export plugins.
        // Export Plugin http://grails.org/plugin/export
        compile ":export:1.5"
        // jQuery UI Plugin http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui
        compile ":jquery-ui:1.10.3"
        // For google visualization you also need google-visualization
        // Google Visualization API Plugin http://grails.org/plugin/google-visualization
        compile ":google-visualization:0.7"
```

**Error message after change**

```
Loading Grails 2.3.8
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.6.2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.6.2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.6.2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.6.2 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.plugins:easygrid:zip:1.6.2
|Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

Comment: Change order of plugins, i bet the same error will occour for :export:1.5 . Looks like your proxy issue is not solved completly.

Comment: I have added proxy settings and able to execute sample projects without these plugins but when I am trying with these plugins then only facing issue. What need to change pls elaborate.

Comment: I've look to plugin page and find that plugin version is `1.6.3` already. Maybe old plugin `1.6.2` is already deleted. That is bad proposition but it may be.